# NodeJS unhandled promise rejection issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, serial-port

I am a NodeJS newbie and I try reading data from a energy meter communicating via COM and show in NodeJS. When I use Promise in a function to return read data from COM port, I have a problem if the return time is over 5 seconds because I install it, it will show a system error. My wish is that if I have data for 5 seconds then return it to me. If the time is over 5 seconds, I want to get "false".

```
function getMeterData(buffer) {
  //Send request to Meter
  meterConnect.write(buffer, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Send request to Meter failed. Detail: " + err.message);
      return false;
    }
  });

  //Get data from the meter
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      reject(false);
    }, 5000);
    meterData.on("data", function(dataReceive, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("The process of receiving data is faulty");
        reject(err);
      }
      clearTimeout(timer);
      resolve(dataReceive);
    });
  });
}
```

The code does not fail when I pass the correct buffer and is returned immediately, but if I send the incorrect buffer, no meter will return the value and after 5 seconds I want to get a false result. But the result is that it returns a pile of errors if after 5 seconds there is no value.

```
(node:19664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: false
(node:19664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return false after 5 seconds, use `resolve(false)` instead of `reject(false)`

Reject is like throwing an error. This will cause your [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to reject, and not return anything.

Using resolve returns a value.

Note that the return value is a promise that resolves to false, not the value false itself. You would need to use .then or await it to get the actual value